# Why are PHP tags not allowed inside a class but outside a function?

Tags: php

Is there a reason why this is considered valid PHP:

```
<?php

class someClass {
    function someFunction() {
?> <?php
    }
}
```

...but this gives a syntax error:

```
<?php

class someClass {
?> <?php
    function someFunction() {
    }
}
```

The syntax error the second example gives is:

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `"function (T_FUNCTION)"' in foo.php on line 4
```

In other words, the PHP parser is fine with PHP start/end tags inside a function, but not inside a class but outside a function, and I'm wondering why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?> <?php` is equivalent* to `echo ' ';`, which would make no sense there.

---

*If you're curious just how equivalent, the opcodes generated for:

```
<?php
echo 'foo';
?>bar<?php
echo 'baz';
```

are:

```
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  E >   ECHO                                                     'foo'
   3     1        ECHO                                                     'bar'
   4     2        ECHO                                                     'baz'
         3      > RETURN                                                   1
```

Comment: Along those same lines though, just `?><?php` with no output is still a syntax error. It should be said that there is no reason why you would need to end php processing in the definition of a class (not it's methods) as nothing could be done outside of the php tags that wouldn't be an error and so it is a syntax error. And yes, I do understand that would be the equivalent of `echo '';`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of php, when you use an end tag, this tells php to begin output buffering (preparing to output data). When you are defining a class, you are defining a set of variables and/or functions, **not** outputting data. However, when you are defining a function within a class you are basically saying - when this function is called perform x tasks within that function which may include outputting data.